# What does "symbolic" mean in this sentence?

Tags: python, symlink, symbolic-math, theano

I'm reading through Bergstra *et al* ["Theano: new features and speed improvements"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.5590) [2012] and do not understand the meaning of "**symbolic**" in this context (versus for instance a symbolic link to a directory) :

> Using Theano’s **symbolically**-defined implementations within a Python
>   loop prevents **symbolic** differentiation through the iterative process,
>   and prevents certain graph optimizations from being applied.
>   Completely unrolling the loop into a **symbolic** chain often leads to an
>   unmanageably large graph and does not allow for “while”-style loops
>   with a variable number of iterations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symbolic in this context refers to [symbolic math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_computation).

This means that you can perform mathematical programming using symbols, instead of needing variables that require numeric values, for example

```
y = x**2 + 5*x + 7
```

For the above to be valid in non-symbolic math, the variable `x` would need to have a numerical value, and the result of the right-hand side would be assigned to `y`, which would then have a numerical value.

Conversely in symbolic math, the variables `x` and `y` could be *symbols* so you could then do something like (in psuedocode)

```
diff(y, x)  # meaning differentiate y with respect to x
```

and it would result in

```
dy/dx = 2*x +5
```

Comment: Just to make this slightly more concrete, in Theano the symbolic differentiation described in this example would be achieved via `dy_dx = theano.grad(y, x)`.

Answer (score 0):

In this context it means that for a variable with `x = 10` only the 'symbol x' of the variable is used for computations. `x+x = 2x` but the value 20 is actually not computed, only the algebraic expression. That way you can e.g. have a series of math operations optimized before inserting the actual values to save computation time or potential other issues like null division.

Not to be confused with but somewhat related is [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation), also used for neural networks, [here's](https://justindomke.wordpress.com/2009/02/17/automatic-differentiation-the-most-criminally-underused-tool-in-the-potential-machine-learning-toolbox/) a good article introducing the concept.